# Writing a Transpose a vector in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have to write a python function where i need to compute the vector
For A is n by n and xn is n by 1

```
r_n = Axn - (xn^TAxn)xn
```

Im using numpy but .T doesn't work on vectors and when I just do

`r_n = A@xn - (xn@A@xn)@xn` but `xn@A@xn` gives me a scaler.

I've tried changing the A with the xn but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You wrote ^T but then never actually applied a transpose. Have you tried applying a transpose?

Comment: what is the real shape of `xn`?  Did you read `np.natmul` docs?

Comment: In `numpy` talking about `vector` and `n by 1` is sloppy thinking.  `numpy` arrays are not all 2d.  They may be 0d (shape `()`), 1d (shape (n,)`, or more.  Transpose does not add dimensions; it just permutes existing dimensions.  It is a logical extension of the switch of dimensions that linear algebra does with 2d arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Making a 3x1 numpy array like this...

```
import numpy as np
       
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

...and then attempting to take its transpose like this...

```
a_transpose = a.T
```

...will, confusingly, return this:

```
# [1 2 3]
```

If you want to define a (column) vector whose transpose you can meaningfully take, and get a row vector in return, you need to define it like this:

```
a = np.reshape(np.array([1, 2, 3]), (3, 1))

print(a)

# [[1]
#  [2]
#  [3]]

a_transpose = a.T

print(a_transpose)

# [[1 2 3]]
```

If you want to define a `1 x n` array whose transpose you can take to get an `n x 1` array, you can do it like this:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

and then get its transpose by calling `a.T`.

Comment: Your original `a` is not 3x1.  Its shape is (3,), it is 1d.  If you want (3,1) use `np.arrat([[1],[2],[3]])`,  the same [] nesting as in the column display.  There's a direct mapping between dimensions and [] nesting in the display (and list input)

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is (n,n) and `xn` is (n,1):

```
A@xn - (xn@A@xn)@xn

(n,n)@(n,1) - ((n,1)@(n,n)@(n,1)) @ (n,1)
(n,1)          error (1 does not match n)
```

If `xn@A@xn` gives scalar that's because `xn` is (n,) shape; as per `np.matmul` docs that's a 2d with two 1d arrays

```
(n,)@(n,n)@(n,) => (n,)@(n,) -> scalar
```

I think you want

```
(1,n) @ (n,n) @ (n,1) => (1,1)
```

Come to think of it that (1,1) array should be same single values as the scalar.

Sample calculation; 1st with the (n,) shape:

```
In [6]: A = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3); x = np.arange(1,4)

In [7]: A@x
Out[7]: array([14, 32, 50])    # (3,3)@(3,)=>(3,)

In [8]: x@A@x         # scalar
Out[8]: 228

In [9]: (x@A@x)@x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 (x@A@x)@x

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 0 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
```

`matmul` does not like to work with scalars.  But we can use `np.dot` instead, or simply multiply:

```
In [10]: (x@A@x)*x
Out[10]: array([228, 456, 684])     # (3,)

In [11]: A@x - (x@A@x)*x
Out[11]: array([-214, -424, -634])
```

Change the array to (3,1):

```
In [12]: xn = x[:,None]; xn.shape
Out[12]: (3, 1)

In [13]: A@xn - (xn.T@A@xn)*xn
Out[13]: 
array([[-214],
       [-424],
       [-634]])         # same numbers but in (3,1) shape
```